# How to change default expand/collapse sub-items in QTreeWidget?

Tags: c++, qt

I tried to create a simple treeview with the following code in Qt 4.8

```
QTreeWidgetItem *city = new QTreeWidgetItem(ui->trvCompetitions);
city->setText(0, tr("City"));

(new QTreeWidgetItem(city))->setText(0, tr("Stockholm"));
(new QTreeWidgetItem(city))->setText(0, tr("Helsinki"));
(new QTreeWidgetItem(city))->setText(0, tr("Copenhagen"));

QTreeWidgetItem *other = new QTreeWidgetItem(ui->trvCompetitions);
other->setText(0, tr("Other"));

(new QTreeWidgetItem(other))->setText(0, tr("London"));
(new QTreeWidgetItem(other))->setText(0, tr("Tokio"));
(new QTreeWidgetItem(other))->setText(0, tr("Hanoi"));
```

And this is the treeview I got

[image: myTreeView]

I have read [this article](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/itemviews-simpletreemodel.html) and I only want my treeview has **expand/collapse sub-items** like that

[image: The TreeView I want to get]

How can I change my treeview like this?

Thank!

Comment: Could you clarify what exactly you want to achieve?  It appears you already have subitems in your tree view.

Comment: @dunc123: I only want my treeview to have structure style (expand/collapse) like image 2 (Title column).

Comment: I think the OP is looking to change the icons on the tree. As in, have the treeview use the boxed + and - icons instead of using triangles for the "expand the node" icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading more documents about QTreeWidget, I realized that the treeview can be customized. I have modified my treeview following [this post](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qtreeview) and the result was good as I desired.

Comment: The link is gone.